# How to authorize user using next auth with nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, authorization, next-auth

I am using next auth for user authentication in my nextjs app, but my end points are on nodejs server (while next auth logic is in api/auth/[...nextauth] file). How can I verify that the user who sent the request from nextjs app to my nodejs server is authorized or not.

Is there a way to send and verify jwt token set by next auth to node js backend and see if user is authenticated or not?

Answer (score 0):

It should be technically possible. For example, you can pass the JWT created by NextAuth to the Node.JS APIs via the Authorization header and decode the JWT using the value of `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const decode = jwt.verify(token, "secret");
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is not working, JWT is not validating that token

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: Major hurdle is next-auth doesn't provide session's jwt.

Answer (score 0):

The JWT token from NextAuth is encrypted. If you try to decode it, you will encounter a malfunction. To access the details of the JWT token

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
const session = getToken({ req, secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET });
```